# Returning a search result in a second Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am struggling on doing a search on a second activity.
When I click on the MainActivity a second activity is started that should allow a search to be performed, and then the result to be returned to the MainActivity.

I am struggling with trying to get the search results to work – so any help would be really appreciated:

1, When I type the text for what I am searching for it is case sensitive. For eg,  in the array there is an item:  “Apple”, if I search for the text “apple” the toast says it didn’t find anything, but when I try and search for “Apple” the toast says “Found one Apple”. So is there an easy way to make the case not case sensitive please?

2, When I click on an item in the list item to be searched through, how do I close the 2nd activity and return to the main activity with the selected item returned please?

Many thanks!

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1

    /* THE GUTS OF IT */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
)
            startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)

        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.d( "TAG","MainActivity 30 - MY_DEBUG" )
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val gotthisInt = data?.getIntExtra("MY_KEY", 1) ?: 1
                Log.d("TAG", "What was received  MY_DEBUG= $gotthisInt")
            }
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Debug - to be deleted -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDebug"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
    android:text="DEBUG IT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Searchbutton"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textDebug"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**SearchActivity.kt**

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
private lateinit var listView: ListView
private lateinit var emptyView: TextView

lateinit var list: ArrayList<String>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    Log.d("TAG", "OnCreate  Starts 101 MY_DEBUG")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.search_main)


    title = "KotlinApp"

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    emptyView = findViewById(R.id.emptyView)
    adapter = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables))

    listView.adapter = adapter
    listView.emptyView = emptyView
    Log.d("TAG", "OnCreate  Starts 199 MY_DEBUG")


}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu - 301 - Gets here MY_DEBUG")
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu,menu)

    val search : MenuItem? = menu?.findItem(R.id.appSearchBar)

    val searchView : SearchView = search?.actionView as SearchView 
    searchView.queryHint = "Search Country..!"
    title = "KotlinApp"

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    list = ArrayList()
    list.add("Apple")
    list.add("Banana")
    list.add("Pineapple")
    list.add("Orange")
    list.add("Mango")
    list.add("Grapes")
    list.add("Lemon")
    list.add("Melon")
    list.add("Watermelon")
    list.add("Papaya")
    adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
    listView.adapter = adapter

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if (list.contains(query)) {
                adapter.filter.filter(query)

                Toast.makeText( this@SearchActivity, "Found one $query",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, "No Match found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })

    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu - 320 - Gets here MY_DEBUG")
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

**search_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SearchActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No Results"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `setOnQueryTextListener` block, use this instead of `query`:

```
list.contains(query.capitalize(Locale.ROOT))
```

or this if your items are always in a specific language:

```
list.contains(query.capitalize(Locale.ENGLISH))
```

To answer your second question, you can attach the result to an intent as an extra and send it to the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

> 1, When I type the text for what I am searching for it is case
> sensitive. For eg, in the array there is an item: “Apple”, if I search
> for the text “apple” the toast says it didn’t find anything, but when
> I try and search for “Apple” the toast says “Found one Apple”. So is
> there an easy way to make the case not case sensitive please?

What you can do is when you compare to strings use method

```
string_item.toLowerCase()
```

This will convert all of your letters to lowercase

```
String item1 = "Apple";
String item2 = "apple";
if (item1.toLowerCase().contentEquals(item2.toLowerCase()) {
     do something
}
```

> 2, When I click on an item in the list item to be searched through, how do I close the 2nd activity and return to the main activity with the selected item returned please?

For this problem you can do it like this

```
int SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in SearchActivity if you want to send data back to MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent .putExtra("result", result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent );
finish();
```

or if you don't want to send data back:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
finish();
```

Just put that inside onClickListner

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent .putExtra("result", result);
                 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent );
                 finish();
            }
        });
```

Then in MainActivity write this code for the `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this in java but you can do it in Kotlin too. Since you are using Kotlin you can check this article for ['A better way to pass data between Activities'](https://proandroiddev.com/is-onactivityresult-deprecated-in-activity-results-api-lets-deep-dive-into-it-302d5cf6edd)

Comment: Many thanks…I’m getting a bit closer! I’ve got the first challenge working (the case sensitivity), but the (clicking on the list and returning the selection) – but I’m struggling on the click to return to the MainActivity. The section “list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()…”. I’ve tried to put this in the onCreateOptionsMenu section – I’m not certain that is correct?I assume that this is Java rather than Kotlin? It says that “setOnItemClickListener” is unresolved – an ideas please? Apologies if I’ve missed-understood something – I’m still quite raw on this stuff

Comment: My code is written in Java, yes. Sorry for that but I am not that good with Kotlin yet. You can put it where you want it. You have listView in onCreateOptionsMenu so just copy there listView.setOnItemClickListener(...) and write the code above. I mean you need to write this in Kotlin.

Comment: That's brilliant! Got it now! Cheers

Comment: @Winny glad I could help. If this helped you close the question and accept the answer if you want. Thanks.